# Предлог в сочетании

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

В вузовских программах 3-го поколения часто применяется предусмотренная министерским стандартом формулировка "используемые **в** аудиторных занятиях". Объясните, пожалуйста, возможно ли здесь применение предлога *в* ("в занятиях"), даже учитывая тот  факт, что мы имеем дело с официально-деловым стилем?

Answer (score 1):

Логичнее, конечно, было бы **на** занятиях, но вряд ли вы где-нибудь найдёте нормативный документ на использование предлогов дядями из министерства.

Comment: Спасибо. И что же - в угоду чиновникам коверкать русский язык?

Comment: Да нет. Речь о том, что победить чиновника невозможно. Вас-то никто не заставляет говорить неграмотно. Хотя это, конечно, зависит от того, сколь часто приходится вам официальные бумаги стряпать.

Comment: Заставляют. Формулировки некоторых пунктов спущенной "рыбы" программ менять нельзя. В этом и ужас ситуации... пишем программы по русскому языку, его же коверкая. АБСУРД!
PS Спасибо за ответ.